Determine all nonzero natural numbers $x$, for which, $2023\times(\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{4x^2-1})\in \mathbb N$
the question
Determine all nonzero natural numbers $x$, for which,
$$2023\times(\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{4x^2-1})\in\mathbb N$$
my idea
Lets note $2023\times(\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{4x^2-1})=N$ , where $N \in \mathbb N$
Every number has the form $\frac{1}{4k^2-1}=\frac{1}{(2k+1)\times(2k-1)}$
So we can write $2023\times(\frac{2}{1*3}+...+\frac{2}{(2x+1)(2x-1)})=2023\times(\sum(\frac{ 1}{(2k+1)\times(2k-1)}))=2023\times(1-\frac{1}{2x+1})=2N=2023\times\frac{2x}{2x+1}$
I don't know what to do forward. Hope one of you can help me!

Well, the factors of $2023$ are $1,7,17,119,289,2023$. As $\frac{2x}{2x+1} $has a odd number as denominator, each of these factors are a suitable denominator.
Hence for $$x=3,2x+1=7$$
$$x=8,2x+1=17$$
$$x=59,2x+1=119$$
$$x=144,2x+1=289$$
$$x=1011,2x+1=2023$$
For these $x$ values, the denominator cancels our, leaving integer answers for the expression

Notice that:$$ (2x,2x+1)=1$$
Hence: $$\quad (2x+1)|2023 $$

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
